# Convergence of Limit

Tags: limits

I have the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \left(n \log a - \log y \right)^n}{(n-1)!}$$ and have to calculate values of $a$ for which it converges for all $y > 0$. Clearly, it holds when $y > a^n$ but what about lower values?

Some basic simulations show that the correct threshold is $a < e,$ but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I notice that when $a < e$, $\log a < 1$, which means the $n \log a$ term goes to $0$ at high powers, but I am unsure about how to use this in a formal proof.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Clearly, it holds when $y>a^n$" If $a > 1$ then there is no value of $y$ that greater than *all* $a^n$.

Comment: Limits don't converge, they exist (or don't). A sequence converges (or doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

By Stirling's approximation we have

$$(n-1)! \sim \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{n}}\left(\frac n e\right)^n$$

therefore

$$\frac{ \left(n \log a - \log y \right)^n}{(n-1)!}\sim \sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi}}\left(e \log a - \frac{e\log y}n \right)^n$$

Comment: Continuing, this should converge whenever the quantity in parentheses is less than $1$ (I think?). Solving, gives $\log a < \frac{1}{e} + \frac{\log y}{n}$. The right term converges to $0$, so we get $a < e^{\frac{1}{e}}.$ However, the answer should be $a < e$ I think... What is the mistake?

Comment: I agree to conclude. If we try with $a=2<e$ the original limit diverges to infinity. Probably there is a typo in the given solution. It seems that $a<e^\frac 1e$ is right.